# Unable to get chromecast sample ios app to work

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

This is what I have done so far: 
1) downloaded the sample ios app from Github (cast-ios-sample)

2) Got my device whitelisted by Google and received App ID, something like this, changed of course, but looks similar to this abcdefgh-1234-5678-abcd-abcdefghijkl.

3) Updated receiver.html file to

```
// Initialize and start the media playing receiver
var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver('abcdefgh-1234-5678-abcd-abcdefghijkl', [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE], "", 5);
```

4)loaded receiver.html in an AWS S3 bucket and made it public (I can download the file from my browser, so I confirmed it is public).
5) In xcode, modified GCKAppDelegate.m as follows:

```
NSLog(@"Setting receiver url.");
//self.host = @"http://www.yourdomain.com/yourreceiver.html";
self.host = @"http://name_of_bucket.amazonaws.com/receiver.html";
```

6) In xcode, modified GCKViewController.m as follows:
    NSLog(@"Starting session.");
    [self.mSession startSessionWithApplication:@"abcdefgh-1234-5678-abcd-abcdefghijkl"                                    argument:self.applicationArgument];

7) I am able to run the application and I can see my Chormecast in the app, but when I select it, I get the following errors in the xcode console:

```
2013-08-09 11:49:20.746 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] executing a GCKStartApplicationRequest with url=http://172.17.1.11:8008/apps/abcdefgh-1234-5678-abcd-abcdefghijkl
2013-08-09 11:49:20.747 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] started POST request for: http://172.17.1.11:8008/apps/abcdefgh-1234-5678-abcd-abcdefghijkl and data: <GCKMimeData: 0xf8089c0>
2013-08-09 11:49:20.748 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] Selected device: ChromecastXXXX
2013-08-09 11:49:20.796 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] httpRequest:didCompleteWithStatusCode:404:data:0 bytes
2013-08-09 11:49:20.796 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] Request failed with error: 5
2013-08-09 11:49:20.796 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] tearDownSessionWithError: Error   Domain=com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError Code=1 "failed to start application (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError)"
2013-08-09 11:49:20.797 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] all teardown steps complete
2013-08-09 11:49:20.797 ChromecastDemoApp[16077:c07] GCK Session failed to start: Error Domain=com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError Code=1 "failed to start application (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError)"
```

8) I am unable to get my web console working by going to localhost:9222.

Any help in what I am doing wrong would be appreciated it.

Comment: 1. Sample code appears to have an issue - I'll see if I can get it fixed.  No need to send Receiver URL from client.  You can pass the content you'd like your Receiver to work with.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sample code appears to have an issue - I'll see if I can get it fixed.  No need to send Receiver URL from client.  You can pass the content you'd like your Receiver to work with.
2. To see if your device is whitelisted it should be :9222 from Chrome.  If that doesn't work, then make sure you set up your device to [x] Send serial # to Google. Without that, your device can never be Whitelisted. (we don't know it's you)

Answer (score 0):

The mAppDelgate.host is not actually used.  The important piece is app-ID.  Ensure that is entered properly in:

[self.mSession startSessionWithApplication:@"YOUR_APP_ID"
                                      argument:self.applicationArgument];

and that the receiver URL you registered with that app-ID matches your receiver.  The 404 error makes me think that URL we have registered with your app_id might have an error.